# Problem generator docxtpl flask - not work save file

Tags: python, flask, docxtpl

I have a problem with my code.
I'm trying to create a docx generator with docxtpl and flask, but I can't get it to work. My intention is to download the file generated with the information acquired from the form.

Here is the code in app.py:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, send_from_directory, url_for, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST',])
def index():
    # generate_report()
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) # When the user click to the "submit" button
def download_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.form
        doc = DocxTemplate("templates/template_procuracao.docx")
        context = {
        'autor':result['autor'],
        'nacionalidade':result['nacionalidade'],
        'estadocivil':result['estadocivil'],
        'identidade':result['identidade'],
        }
        doc.render(context)
        doc.save()
        return send_file('templates/output',
        attachment_filename='teste.docx',
        as_attachment=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Here is the code in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="autor" name="autor" placeholder="AUTOR"><br>
        <input type="text" id="nacionalidade" name="nacionalidade" placeholder="NACIONALIDADE"><br>
        <input type="text" id="estadocivil" name="estadocivil" placeholder="ESTADOCIVIL"><br>
        <input type="text" id="identidade" name="identidade" placeholder="IDENTIDADE"><br>
        <a href="{{url_for('download_file')}}" type="submit">Submit</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

after clicking the submit button nothing happens.
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2022 21:00:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2022 21:00:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Answer (score 0):

When you save your document you need to save it in memory to essentially create a file to send (unless you want to save it as a file and then load it again). You are also trying to send a file `'templates/output'` and not the document you'd created.

```
from io import BytesIO

...
def download_file():
    ...
    docx_in_memory = BytesIO()
    doc.render(context)
    doc.save(docx_in_memory)

    docx_in_memory.seek(0)

    return send_file(
        docx_in_memory,
        attachment_filename='teste.docx',
        as_attachment=True)
```